# Static Resources not work in Xamarin Oreo emulator

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Xamarin project I have many static resources styles defined. This worked perfectly in my Nougat emulator. Suddenly, after upgrading to Oreo 8.1, I discovered the style are not set anymore.

I use the latest update of Visual Studio 2017. 
As an example I defined a style in the App.xaml as follow:

```
    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="pageStyle" TargetType="ContentPage">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions"
                    Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions"
                    Value="Start" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In my content page, I consumed this style at this way:

```
         <Label Text="Nieuwe bestelling"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               Style="{StaticResource headerStyle}" />
```

My problem is that the headerStyle doesn't work. No error message will be displayed and the style is not set in my Android project.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks,
Marcel

Comment: Hello, your codew works well on my phone, 8.1, yellow, bold,large. Try reinstall the app or restart your phone.

Comment: Both, on my emulator and on my phone the style wasn't set. I cleaned and rebuild my application. Nothing seems to solve my problem. More help would be appreciated.

Comment: Delete the bin and obj folder, and restart your VS.

Comment: Try to change `headerStyle` to other name? Or refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) to check .

Comment: Hi Joe, None of your recommendations solved me problem. After a few hours of searching I discovered I can't use StaticResources anymore. When I used Dynamic Resources, the styles worked again. This link pointed me in the right direction: https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/